# Seeking help with the application of Law of Large Numbers and Central Limit Theorem to calculate Investor Risk

Tags: finance, probability-limit-theorems, central-limit-theorem, law-of-large-numbers, calculator

I'm a newbie to the forum with zero financial or statistical skills - first time post...seeking some assistance and a solution..thanks in advance!

I am trying to create a investor calculator or at least an accurate calculation of the following scenario for a financial instrument I'm aiming test as an MVP:

Say a loan is required and a funding pool of investors *(N)* is established to finance the loan amount *(X)*.

Hence, the loan amount *$(X)* is sought by a borrower for an annual percentage yield *(APY)* of *(Y)%*.

E.g.: $2000 pooled from a number of willing investors *(N)* at an APY of 8.5% for a required term *(T)*.

**Risk assumptions** (Outcomes) are as follows:

- 80% probability of no loss
- 10% probability of 50% loss
- 10% probability of total loss

**Solution sought:**

- The number of investors *(N)* required to reach zero (0) risk

**Variables:**

- The effect of an annual premium $*(P)* paid by a Borrower to reduce *(N)*
- The effect of a funded retention *(FR)*% to mitigate future losses
- The level of risk *(R)%* in the event that investor numbers *(N)* are altered (ideally <10).

Thanks again!!!